# removeAllViews and setContentView not working

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a problem with removeAllViews and setContentView..... both are not working for me i don't know why.
I have a function in a class that return a view and i want to add that view to the screen and that view will be change after every 5 second.....
so after 5 second i call removeAllViews on the layout in which the view is added and then add it again.... but surprisingly the old view is still there and it add the new view at the end....

Same problem with the setContentView i try this also but it also work same as main layout it also add the view at the end not replace the whole screen.......

please help...... thanks in advance............

```
setContentView(logic.getView());
```

and

```
LinearLayout layout = blah blah blah;
layout.removeAllViews();
layout.addView(logic.getView(), layout parameters....);
```

Comment: As @AdilSoomro said can you show your code please

Comment: also tried invalidate() but not working.........:(

Comment: Have you try it with just for once occurence ? I mean try to remove and add view just for once and not for continues every 5 second. Will it be work ? Just ping me with the result of this.

Comment: post your real code, because those are two things that should not be a problem. So the problem is probably something to do with the logic part.

Comment: @iDroidExplorer i just add the view and after five second i remove the view it works.... it remove the view from screen...... :@

Comment: @iDroidExplorer and when i try to add the view again it add it two times yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy??????????

Comment: I got the solution thanks for every one.... thanksssssss there is a problem in view creating i have the old data too in the arrays :P thumbs up for @iDroidExplorer... thanks again....

Comment: @user1031944 : ok I got your issue. still your view is not removed properly thats why it appears two times. means the first added remains and new one is added. So it appear as twise. Now just put your xml code where you are going to add your view and also the java code that you use to remove the view and add.

Comment: @iDroidExplorer no the issue is solved make an answer so i can tick it thanks...

Comment: @Hamdullahshah: I have posted answer. Please accept it.

Comment: @Hamdullahshah: still you havent acepted the answer. If you got the answer then you must have to accept it. So it can help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. With some of the review of your comments i got why this issue is created.

May be You are not removing the first View properly. Thats why while you are going to add another view, there are two views(1st is previous one and second is newly added view) instead of the one new View.

**So remove the first view properly and then add the view as you want.**

Hope it will help you.

Thanks.

Enjoy. :)

Comment: Thanks for accept the right answer. And you can upvote it so it also help other more.

Answer (score 0):

- **`1. Using Visiblity...`**

  Look at the setVisibility method to change the visibility options for
  the view. Here

[developer.android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int)

```
- **` 2.Runtime Add And Delete View`**  


LinearLayout layout;
    TextView textview1 ,textview;
    Button btn ;
layout =new LinearLayout(this);
        LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1.0f);
        layout.setLayoutParams(params);

        btn = new Button(this);
        LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);

        btn.setLayoutParams(param);
        btn.setText("Change");

       textview =new TextView(this);
       textview.setLayoutParams(param);
       textview.setText("Text 1...");


       textview1 =new TextView(this);
       textview1.setLayoutParams(param);
       textview1.setText("Text 2 ...");

        layout.addView(textview);
        layout.addView(btn);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.i("Remove All View ", "REmove");
                layout.removeAllViews();
                layout.addView(textview1);
                layout.addView(btn);
                Log.i("Remove All View ", "REmove");
            }
        });
        setContentView(layout);
```

Comment: @user1031944 layout.setVisibility(View.INVISBLE) here link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:visibility

Comment: ohh No i don't want to invisible it i just want to remove it and add it again.....

Comment: I understand u r requriement... u r code perfect but u want to add setContentView(logic.getView()); After Layout declare